# Django - modal form and resubmission on page reload

Tags: django, django-forms

I have got a modal contact form. The form works fine, but the page reload resubmits previously entered values.

**view.py**

```
...
if request.POST:
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        entry = form.save()
        form = ContactForm()
        c.update(locals())
        return render(request, 'template.html', c )
...
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="." method="post" id="contact-form">
...
</form>
```

I tried to clear the form in the GET request. Form fields are cleared, but this does not prevent submission on the page reload.

```
else: #request.GET
    form = ContactForm()
    c.update(locals())
    return render(request, 'template.html', c )
```

I have seen many examples suggesting a redirect. I do understand this approach, but in case of a modal form I would like to avoid a redirect.

How to prevent modal form re-submissions? Is the redirect really the only way?

Comment: What about using AJAX?

Comment: Can you please expand on the suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution seems very simple:

Replaced this line...

```
return render(request, 'template.html', c )
```

... with the one below:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```